# Starting out with d3.js visualizations

Tags: javascript, html, json, d3.js

I'm new to d3.js. I just set up a local server and i'm trying to load a sample json file into my html file to play around with different visualizations. Nothing will display when i open it in my browser, & I'm getting this error in the console. "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null"

See code below. First block is the .html file and the second block is the sample .json. Thanks!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
<title> D3 Arrays </title>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"> </script>
</head>

<body>

<script>

d3.json("mydata.json", function (data) {

    var canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", 500)
        .attr("height", 500)

    canvas.selectAll("rect")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
            .append("rect")
            .attr("width", function (d) { return d.age * 10;})
            .attr("height", 50)
            .attr("y", function (d, i) { return i * 48; })
            .attr("fill", "blue")
})


</script>

</body>

</html>
```

json data

```
[

{"name": "Judy", "age": 56},
{"name": "Glen", "age": 59},
{"name": "Dave", "age": 23}

]
```

Comment: Where is second block? Where do you try to read length?

Comment: you are also missing the x attribute for the rectangles

Comment: Works for me -- https://vida.io/documents/XH7kPcWCD5C2erJZC

Comment: How is it possible that you get error message containing word "length", if there is no "length" in your code?

Comment: Your data must be null. That's the only way for you to get error with "length", which btw must come from d3.js, from within data(data). And your data is null because you have situation that Pablo Navaro described below, or some other mistake, like wrong file path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null

from the message,  maybe you did not load the json correctly. you can check the data before

pass it to d3.

```
d3.json("mydata.json", function (data) {

console.log(data); // check the console output to judge if you get the data

var canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 500)
    .attr("height", 500)

canvas.selectAll("rect")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("width", function (d) { return d.age * 10;})
        .attr("height", 50)
        .attr("y", function (d, i) { return i * 48; })
        .attr("fill", "blue")
```

})

i copy your code and data to http://jsfiddle.net/x5WzU/ and it works correctly

so:

**check your server to check the path of mydata.json**

Comment: Thats what I said above.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument in the `d3.json` callback is the error, and the second is the parsed data. If you don't have errors loading or parsing the data, your `data` variable will be `null`. You should use:

```
d3.json('mydata.json', function(error, data) {

    if (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }

    // visualization code...

});
```

Regards,